# React Native - react-native-mapbox-gl vs react-native-maps

Tags: maps, mapbox-gl

I have to develop apps with React Native for mobile that concern with mapping and found out there are two libraries for Native on this - [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) and [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps). From github pages and tutorials I see no big difference on what they can achieve. I can't decide which one to choose and can't afford to change later because one does not meet what I need. What I want the apps to do is to:

- show markers and routes
- work great with GeoJson and PostGIS
- better performance on both Android and iOS

Which one would have advantage over another?

Comment: What do you mean by work `great` with GeoJSON... can you elaborate in your question.

Comment: Ease of parsing GeoJSON data... like in Leaflet... I believe they have this as a basic feature...

Answer (score 2):

I have done an app with react-native-maps and haven't used mapbox one. If you need to have a larger number of markers displayed at once it's tricky to get there (you'd have to fork the repository and change something in the Android/iOS parts of the codebase).

There should be no issues displaying 50 markers on the map but the CPU explodes (that's I guess one of the reasons why AirBnB in their app does not have many markers and limits the number when you look at a small region with hundreds of locations).

Given that mapbox seems to be more low level I guess there would be no issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Create-React-Native-App (Expo) to kick off your project, react-native-map is already included... I've done a bunch of Leaflet and Django work in the past, I found it pretty straight-forward to get going with this approach.

Adding Mapbox to Expo is "In Progress" https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-mapbox-gl-support

I find the documentation for react-native-maps to be more example based (easier to understand) where as the Mapbox docs are API definition driven. Good, but not as approachable for those new to React-Native their library.

They will both work with GeoJson, no worries.

Comment: They improved how you integrate mapbox into expo!

Here are the instructions:
https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/plugin/install.md

You may also want to check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6b-TXFtJDs

Answer (score 1):

To complement on the answers:

react-native-mapbox-gl is a lot more feature complete, for sure. but there is a huge catch: you'll need to eject your project.

If you are comfortable working with a much different workflow then what expo gives you, then eject it and go the react-native-mapbox-gl route.

I'm not a mobile developer at all and I suffered a lot to get it working on a toy project.

If your application is simple, I'm sure the regular react-native-maps will work just fine. The velocity you gain from expo cannot be compared with maintaining a much more complex project, **just** to use mapbox-gl. If you require, of course, change, but if not, don't.